# XSLT copy without segment name

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<segment>
    <personal_information>
        <birth_name>xxx</birth_name>
        <created_by>yyy</created_by>
        <created_on_timestamp>2018-08-06T06:41:07.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
    </personal_information>
<segment>
```

I want to copy the entire personal_information segment with all elements and sub-segments while adding a new field. I tried this with:

```
<segment>
    <personal_information>
        <action>DELETE</action>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </personal_information>
</segment>
```

But this results in the following:

```
<segment>
    <personal_information>
        <action>DELETE</action>
        <personal_information>
            <birth_name>xxx</birth_name>
            <created_by>yyy</created_by>
            <created_on_timestamp>2018-08-06T06:41:07.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
        </personal_information>
    </personal_information>
</segment>
```

Would would be the XSLT code to achieve this as a result:

```
<segment>
    <personal_information>
        <action>DELETE</action>
        <birth_name>xxx</birth_name>
        <created_by>yyy</created_by>
        <created_on_timestamp>2018-08-06T06:41:07.000Z</created_on_timestamp>
    </personal_information>
</segment>
```

I do not want to copy all fields one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<xsl:copy>`, use **`<xsl:copy-of>`**, which accepts an `XPath` expression for the nodes to be included in the copy; in this case only the inner childnodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="segment">
        <segment>
            <personal_information>
                <action>DELETE</action>
                <xsl:copy-of select="personal_information/*" />         
            </personal_information>
        </segment>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You need a identity template and one personal_information with adding one action element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal_information">
        <xsl:copy>
            <action>DELETE</action>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work as expected, but the personal_information template needs to be suppressed due to other restrictions. I'll check if I can improve this with a param.

Comment: Update your desire output i answered as per your requested output.

Answer (score 0):

Updated as per new requirement :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personal_information">
            <action>DELETE</action>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```